# iptables on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, iptables, port

I'm trying to open a port on CentOS, but it doesn't seem to work: port 16 seems to be closed and 4075 seems to be open, even though according to iptables it should be visa versa.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       30  1920 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:445
2        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:445
3     8071  630K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:137
4      516  110K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:138
5       17  1064 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:139
6        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:16
7        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:16
8     5533 8865K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
9        6   432 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
10       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11       3   872 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
12    2320  277K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 26 packets, 1776 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination



[root@titan ~]# telnet localhost 16 Trying ::1... telnet: connect to
address ::1: Connection refused 
[root@titan ~]# telnet localhost 4075
Trying ::1... Connected to localhost.
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Opened the port in ip6tables, still unable to connect

```
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 16 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 16 -j ACCEPT

telnet localhost 16
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

**UPDATE 2** I figured it out. I didn't realize I needed a service to be listening to a port in order to be able to connect with telnet. Thanks everyone.

Comment: The iptables you're looking at at is ipv4, while the telnet session is connecting via ipv6. Try connecting using 127.0.0.1 and post the results.

Comment: Same result =(
`telnet 127.0.0.1 16
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem myself. first, you should log out of your ssh session and then connect to the machine. This is because most iptables don't block the loopback interface. 
Secondly as in the comment you were using ipv6. I think you're problem is not in the iptables. in most cases your iptables doesn't deny anything on your localhost, but the server accessible through port 4075 can speak ipv6 and the server on port 16 can't, but your telnet command doesn't make use of ipv4. I think this because I am missing the try to connect to 127.0.0.1. my telnet (to any not open port) is like that

```
$ telnet localhost 12334
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

so he is first trying ipv6 which is preferred, and afterwards, after a connection refused, it tries connecting via ipv4.

**EDIT** I saw your comment, so maybe something with your service is wrong.... 
can you try logging every dropped package? [here is an article I have found](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/)

Comment: Well in my case it looks like telnet tried using only ipv6, not ipv4 (according to: "Trying ::1...")

Comment: that's what I said, the telnet command doesn't use ipv4

Answer (score 0):

IPTables works for IPV4 but not IPV6.   Use ip6tables.